# convert first row data to dictionary and remove nan values

Tags: pandas

I need to convert the first row to a dictionary and then remove all "nan" values. This works...

```
pd.Series(df.head(1).T.to_dict()[0]).dropna()
```

Or. this one...

```
df.head(1).dropna(axis=1).T.to_dict()[0]
```

But is there any other way to achive this? The type of dataframe is sparse, if that matters.

```
type(df)
pandas.core.sparse.frame.SparseDataFrame
```

I am asking because I do not think it is pythonic and I guess there must be a method to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.iloc[0].dropna().to_dict()
```

is shorter and does not require any transposing.

the `.iloc` method returns a series when provided a single row index, which is then cleansed of null-values & converted to a dictionary.

Comment: it is also faster !!